# python-selenium returning element is not interactable error

Tags: python, selenium, gwt, xpath

I am using selenium-python binding. I am getting the following error while trying to select and manipulate an element. (using Chromedriver)

```
Message: invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated
```

I think the element is successfully selected with the following syntax: but I cannot manipulate it with, for example, clear() or send_keys("some value"). I would like to fill the text area, but I cannot make it work. If you have experienced similar problems, please share your thought. Thank you.

UPDATE: I noticed html is changing as I manually type to style="display: none" that might be a reason for this error. Modified the code below. Can you please point out any solution?

```
driver.find_element(by='xpath', value="//table[@class='input table']//input[@id='gwt-debug-url-suggest-box']")
```

or

`driver.find_element(by='xpath', value="//input[@id='gwt-debug-url-suggest-box']")`

or

```
driver.find_element_by_id("gwt-uid-47")
```

or

```
driver.find_element(by='xpath', value="//div[contains(@class, 'sppb-b')][normalize-space()='www.example.com/page']")
```

Here is the html source code:

```
<div>
    <div class="spH-c" id="gwt-uid-64"> Your landing page </div>
    <div class="spH-f">
        <table class="input-table" width="100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="spA-e">
                        <div class="sppb-a" id="gwt-uid-47">
                            <div class="sppb-b spA-b" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">www.example.com/page</div>
                            <input type="text" class="spC-a sppb-c" id="gwt-debug-url-suggest-box" aria-labelledby="gwt-uid-64 gwt-uid-47" dir="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="error" style="display:none" id="gwt-debug-invalid-url-error-message" role="alert"> Please enter a valid URL. </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="spB-b">
                            <div class="spB-a" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: When you focus/click the element in the browser - do you see the relevant part of the HTML changing? Thanks.

Comment: yes, I just noticed html is changing as I manually type like <div class="sppb-b spA-b" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">www.example.com/page</div> ; please note: display is now none. Any solution to this

Comment: I've updated an answer a little bit. It's difficult to tell without being able to reproduce the issue. I suspect there is a different element appearing after you click the suggest box. Try to inspect the element that you type in the browser manually - is it the same suggest box? Hope that helps.

Comment: yes, the box remains the same. just that div becomes invisible as I actually type letters, clicking , however, does not change anything

Comment: Okay, updated with one more guess.

Comment: okay, as I try to click, it tells element is not visible --- another error. a new element is added dir="ltr"

Comment: Then, it sounds like the previous theory is valid - this input element gets invisible on click and a different one is visible - you should send keys to this different element. I don't know what to add more here.

Comment: Hi, action chains worked

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried selecting by:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("gwt-debug-url-suggest-box")
driver.send_keys("Your input")
```

This way you are selecting the input directly.
Anyway,the link to the page would help.